# Objective C - unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2829fe980

Tags: objective-c

I'm calling this method:

```
- (void)allServerListsWithCompletion:(void(^_Nullable)(NSArray<VPNUServerItem *> *_Nullable allServerItems,
                                                       NSArray<VPNUServerItem *> *_Nullable streamServerItems,
                                                       NSArray<VPNUServerItem *> *_Nullable personalServerItems,
                                                       NSArray<VPNUServerItem *> *_Nullable optimalServerItems,
                                                       NSError *_Nullable error))completion;
```

And doing this:

```
 [KSVPNUFacade.defaultFacade allServerListsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *allServerItems,
                                                               NSArray *streamServerItems,
                                                               NSArray *personalServerItems,
                                                               NSArray *optimalServerItems,
                                                               NSError *error) {
}];
```

But every time the method `allServerListsWithCompletion` is called, I get the error:

> allServerListsWithCompletion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x280e87000

How can I fix it? That's the exactly line where I'm getting the error

Comment: And you are calling the code from Objective-C also? . I just tried your header  and didn't get any issues.

Comment: I'm calling from swift, but I dont know what else I can test. This is the complete trace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767048/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-swift-5

Comment: Can you show full error message? Because it could be that `defaultFacade` has been override or badly set? So the full error message should give the real class of `defaultFacade`.